# Signal R # Multiple Azure Function with SPA application?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

I have spa application with more then 100 microservices and more then 50 azure functions.

I m using Java script with Singlan R library.

I have more then 50 azure function so my first question do we really  need below code for all 50 function app as w have only one azure singal R Hub #

```
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
public SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]HttpRequest req)
{
    return Negotiate(req.Headers["x-ms-signalr-user-id"], GetClaims(req.Headers["Authorization"]));
}
```

and as I have more then 10 service plan which Url i should use at client side for connection with Signal R Hub ?

```
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/3.1.7/signalr.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    let messages = document.querySelector('#messages');
    const apiBaseUrl = window.location.origin;
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        ****.withUrl(apiBaseUrl + '/api')****
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .build();
      connection.on('newMessage', (message) => {
        document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = message;
      });

      connection.start()
        .catch(console.error);
  </script>
```